# Trigonometric Double Angle proof

Tags: trigonometry

Below is the trigonometric double angle problem. Please prove this.

> If $\tan θ=\sec 2α$, prove that $\sin 2θ=\dfrac{1-\tan 4α}{1+\tan 4α}$

What I have tried:

> R.H.S = $\dfrac{1-\tan 4α}{1+\tan 4α}$
>
> = $\dfrac{cos4α-\sin4α}{cos4α+sin4α}$
>
> = $\dfrac{cos^2(2α) - sin^2(2α) - 2sin2αcos2α}{cos^2(2α) - sin^2(2α) + 2sin2αcos2α}$
>
> .....
>
> ......

Just the hit will do.

Sorry everybody, it was a false proof, just got the wrong questions. It was supposed to be

$\sin 2θ=\dfrac{1-\tan^4α}{1+\tan^4α}$

And i have solved it already, thanks everyone for valuable comments.

Comment: ..and you have done **what** so far?

Comment: I tried to prove from the RHS, converting tan4α to sin4α/cos4α and then solving and applying double angle formula on cos4α with cos2.2α and then apply 1/cos2α=tanθ....

Comment: Then you should *add* that to your question, perhaps under "I"ve tried the following:" or like that, otherwise most members will think you're tying others to do your homework for you and, besides downvoting you, perhaps you'll get your question closed.

Comment: @DonAntonio can you just provide the hint so that I can prove it myself

Comment: Oh, I don't know @user065 . I tried 2-3 things, but it seems way too involved and I'm lazy...if I come up with some slick trick I shall write it.

Comment: Haven't tried this myself but it might be worth using the half-angle identity: $$\sin(2\theta)=\frac{2\tan(\theta)}{1+\tan^2(\theta)}$$

Comment: I tried that too, and stuck at $\dfrac{2cos2α}{cos^2(2α)+1}$

Comment: By using $\sin^2 \alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$ and $\tan \alpha=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}$ you should come quite far I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false.

Choose $\theta=\arctan (-2)$ and $\alpha=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$. Then $\tan \theta=\sec 2\alpha$.

But $\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta=-2\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac{\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}}\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac1{1+\tan^2\theta}}=-2\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac45}\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac15} =-0.8$

and $\dfrac{1-\tan 4\alpha}{1+\tan 4\alpha}=\dfrac{1-\sqrt3}{1+\sqrt3}=2-\sqrt3\not=-0.8.$

Comment: ya you are right. I got the wrong question. It was supposed to be tan to fourth power of alpha. Thanks